# Should I fix posts where imgur is being flaky?

Tags: discussion

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37083/how-can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-delay/37098#37098) where some of the `i.stack.imgur` images were "no longer available", so I converted them to `i.imgur`. Discussion on *[imgur.com is deleting images](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1523/imgur-com-is-deleting-images)* makes it sound like this shouldn't happen any more and that it's better to keep i.stack.imgur.

It's bad to have answers with invalid pictures, but it sounds like we should always use i.stack.imgur.

What should I do? Is there a place to report broken images?

Comment: All the broken Images I saw eventually came back (without editing). Favourite the question and wait a day, then re-upload the image via the Interface (clicking the (img) button). That should be the safest way to go, assuming you can get to the original image somehow. If not, well, I've no idea :)

Comment: I have since rehosted those to the official SE account, which means they won't disappear in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image was uploaded using the image upload button within the SE editor toolbar, the image should work.  If the image was uploaded to imgur *separately* since the time that SE has used a pro imgur account, then yes, just edit it and move on.  If it is an image uploaded to the SE account that is broken, *those* are the ones that should absolutely work and we would want to know about.

Comment: The images were added by desgua on May 7th. imgur lists the images as being uploaded a month ago. Since I didn't upload the images, I can't comment on the method used.

Comment: "we would want to know about" What's the best way to do that? Flag for moderator attention, post on meta, ...?

Comment: @pydave flag it for moderator attention. There's a one-time fix here that will affect users who did NOT use our built-in image upload support.