# Images to apt links not appearing?

Tags: bug, apturl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software centre image link is broken](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1852/software-centre-image-link-is-broken)

I keep seeing the message 'the image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available', and I discovered this only happens with apt links. Here's an example, from a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75505/how-do-i-stop-that-launcher-from-popping-up-when-mouse-goes-to-the-left-edge) made just a few days ago:

[image: image error]

This post '[How to post links that install software via apt?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-install-software-via-apt)' also has the image error in the first answer.

I found [this post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1523/imgur-com-is-deleting-images) from earlier this year that says this is a temporary problem, and images only have to be viewed one time per 6 months. The first link and the image above are from a post less than a week old, so why am I seeing the error message?